# Adding a variable which corresponds to looping variable for each loop

Tags: stata

I have two variables message_one and message_two.

While looping over variables, I want to display message_one if "vari" is varone, and display message_two if "vari" is vartwo.

What I want to do is different but this is an example.

I am doing the following and it does not work.

```
foreach vari in varone vartwo {

local suffix "one" if `vari'==varone
local suffix "two" if `vari'==vartwo

display(message_`suffix')

}
```

How should I change the local lines to make it work?

That is, I want to add a variable which corresponds to the looping variable for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` condition won't work here. In general, it identifies observations that satisfy some condition. In particular, that makes no sense as qualifying `local` as there is no implicit loop over observations in assigning contents to a macro. So, the likely consequence of your syntax is an illegal syntax message ("does not work" is never a precise problem report).

However, note that the effect of something  like

```
 local foo if 2 == 2
```

is just to copy the text `if 2 == 2` into local macro `foo`.

What you want is perhaps more like

```
foreach vari in varone vartwo {
       di cond("`vari'" == "varone", "one", "two") 
}
```

but that loop is pointless as a single direct statement suffices:

```
di "one" _n "two"
```

You could do this instead:

```
foreach vari in varone vartwo {
       if "`vari'" == "varone" di "one" 
       else di "two" 
}
```

The `if` command here is quite different from the `if` qualifier.

I have had to make guesses at what you want here.

First, I added double quotes on the surmise that you want to compare strings directly. If you want something else, please explain.

Second, a statement like

```
display(message_one)
```

would work if and only if `message_one` were a predefined variable (in which case you would see a display of its value in the first observation) or a predefined scalar. But storing a single text message in a variable is unnecessary, especially if the same text is repeated in every observation, as it would be with something like

```
  gen foo = "this message"
```

In Stata that is not a good way to define a scalar. Just defining a message as a literal text string within a program is almost always simplest and best.

What you asked is evidently a minimal version of your real problem, but equally I don't know what that real problem is.